# SQL Server group

Tags: grouping

I have a sql server database table with columns as shown below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz0Hg.jpg)

I want to get an output something like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bUnU.jpg)

I cannot figure out how I can group only zeros listed for EPID and group only ones in my query ? Can anyone point me out how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to query for `(EPID=='A' AND isRequired==1) OR EPID=='B'`, is that right? Here's a guess:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE (EPID = 'A' AND isRequired = 1)
OR (EPID = 'B');
```

Comment: I can't use EPID = 'A' because there are several other EPIDs as well